# RAID 1 vs background copying daemon

Tags: debian, raid, hard-drive, mdadm, raid-1

I'm using my Raspberry Pi as a Linux powered NAS. I have two old HDDs, one of which is near failure and the other seems fine. I want to mirror the drives for redundancy.

I've tried setting up a RAID 1 using mdadm, but I ran into many problems, so I was wondering if it wouldn't be easier to just mount both drives, and use a daemon working in the background to mirror the drives. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: I explained my situation as to why I ask the question, but I believe the question itself is very much relevant to businesses who may want advice on both options for their servers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to use a failing drive, and especially not in a RAID array. It's too easy for something to go wrong. RAID is usually used so that if a drive starts to fail, you can remove it, and not the other way around.

It would probably be best to simply copy the data from the failing drive to the working one. You could use `rsync` to copy the files from one drive to another -- if the copy fails or new data is added, you can run `rsync` again to update the new drive without starting over.

I wouldn't automate replication of the drives with a daemon or cron job, as any corruption introduced by the failing drive may be copied to the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a failing drive for this. If you want to mirror drives, that's fine, but use functional drives.

RAID makes no promises of data integrity. RAID replicates block datasets across drives, and will sustain a potential drive failure. Keeping a failed drive in the array will lead to horrific performance and overhead, filesystem corruption, and a bad day.

RAID 1 with Linux MD should be very cut and dry. You don't mention the problems you ran into, so I can't comment on them. Using a daemon in the background to mirror filesystems would not be an ideal solution for a LOT of reasons.

Comment: And what are those reasons?